# How can I use a javascript generator with sloth.js?

Tags: javascript

This question requires knowledge of the javascript **sloth** library located here: https://github.com/rfw/sloth.js

If I have this javascript generator.

```
function fibonacci(){
  var fn1 = 1;
  var fn2 = 1;

  while (1){
    var current = fn2;
    fn2 = fn1;
    fn1 = fn1 + current;
    yield current;
  }
}
```

With the sloth library I can turn it into an iterator that is suitable for usage with the sloth library.

```
var iter = sloth.iterNextable(fibonacci());
```

The sloth docs at the above URL show examples of using the take() function to take n elements from a sloth-friendly iterator:

```
sloth.ify([1, 2, 3]).take(2).force();
[ 1, 2 ]
```

The question: how to get from my fibonacci() generator to a slothified object that I can call take() on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. The reason I posted the question is that this

```
sloth.ify(iter).take(5)
```

returned

```
[object Object]
```

So I assumed I was doing something wrong.  This object was a lazy object that needed to be eval'ed.  This is where force() comes in:

```
sloth.ify(iter).take(5).force()
```

returns

```
1,1,2,3,5
```